# Ternary operation. Does it exist?

Tags: operator-theory

Everybody knows unitary operations. They are obviously exist. For example, an operation of factorial (n!).
Everybody also knows binary operations: summation, multiplication, exponent, etc.
We could imagine a ternary operation. It could be some function that takes three numbers and results with another number: the sum of three numbers, or the sum of the first number with the second number raised to the power of third... But all ternary operations I am able to imagine can be represented as the composition of binary ones.
So I found myself thinking about existing of a ternary operation that cannot be represented as a composition of binaries. Unfortunately I haven't found any so far.
Does anybody know anything about such odd things?

Comment: See [Ternary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

Comment: See also [Median algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_algebra).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is an *infinite* set and $f:X\times X\times X\to X$ is any ternary operation on $X$, we can always find $g, h:X\times X\to X$ such that
$$ f(x,y,z) = g(x,h(y,z)) $$
The slick proof of this uses the axiom of choice to construct $h$ such that it is a *bijection* $X\times X\to X$, and then the above equation can serve as a definition of $g$ if we read it right to left.

---

It is not quite as nice when $X$ is finite. For example if $X=\{0,1\}$, then the *majority function* (whose out is the one of $0$ or $1$ that appears two or three times among the inputs) cannot be represented in this way.

But if we allow duplication of the inputs, we *can* always represent it in the form
$$ f(x,y,z) = k_1(g_1(x,h_1(y,z)), k_2(\cdots, k_{n-1}(g_{n-1}(x,h_{n-1}(y,z)), g_n(x,h_n(y,z)))\cdots))$$
for some finite $n$ and appropriate binary functions $k_i$, $g_i$, $h_i$.

(Namely, each pair of $g_i$ and $h_i$ can encode at least one line in a tabulation of $f$, and the $k$s can discard the results of the $g_i,h_i$ combos that don't "fire". In fact all of the $k_i$s can be chosen to be equal).

---

We can also do with fewer *different* binary functions at the cost of more complex expressions: For $X=\{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}$, define
$$ x\mathop\downarrow y = \begin{cases} x-1 & \text{if }x=y\ne 0 \\ m-1 & \text{if }x=y=0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
Then *any function whatsoever* $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ from $X^n$ to $X$ can be represented as an expression built *only* from binary $\downarrow$s and the variables $x_1$ through $x_n$.

(In the case $m=2$, $\downarrow$ becomes the Boolean NOR operator).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! But what did you mean when said "if we allow duplication of the inputs"?

Comment: @MikalaiParshutsich: I mean that the representation of $f$ that follows has several occurrences of each of $x$, $y$, $z$ on the right-hand side. (This may or may not be something you care about).